# What table should the answer be stored in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

The project currently has 3 tables, a users a competitions and competitions_users.

The idea is that admin can create competitions and users can enter them. I have competitions storing all of the competition details and users storing the user details, my competitions_users is just storing foreign id's from competitions and users so they can be linked, many users can have many competitions.

The issue comes when I want a user to answer a question, I cant store an answer in the competitions table as that would create loads of duplicate data the same goes for users. I'm not exactly sure where to store it at all. I thought about having a stand alone table called answers but I cant be sure exactly how to implement it in connection to the others.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say having an `answers` table is the way to go.

I'm assuming you use ActiveRecord for your models, so off the top of my head I would have something like:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :competition
end
```

You will probably need something more involved to link an answer to a specific question etc, but maybe this gives the general idea.

---

Here are what the other classes could look like to accommodate this:

```
class Competition < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    has_many :answers
    ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :competitions
    has_many :answers
    ...
end
```

Comment: this is exactly what my users_competitions model looks like, should I use that to store the answer instead? or is it wrong to store data other than the foreign keys in a table built to create the relationship between other tables?

Comment: arg0: See my edit, you should probably make use of `has_and_belongs_to_many` which creates the join table for you. Check the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: Overall you might want to extract more things into their own models (and thus their own tables). `Question` is a good candidate. I've been trying to teach myself not to be afraid of having many tables. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is totally depending on you. I'll suggest a separate table called

ANSWERS : Question_ID(FK:competition.id), CORRECT ANSWER
USER_ANSWER: USER_ID, COMP_ID, QUES_NUM, WRITE/WRONG, USERS_ANSWER

For simplifying, sky is the limit.

Comment: so in this solution the answer can only see the competition_id as a foreign key, should the user_id here be a foreign key also? because if the user id isn't captured along with the competition id then I think it would be possible to enter a given competition many times.

Comment: ANSWER Table will keep correct answer to the questions in a competition. You can keep question number and competition number for it. USER_ANSWER will have foreign keys from all the tables.